# No Data Posted in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I use a form which sends data with a POST method to a php file via AJAX. Everything is ok and I can see the results in the html table in its id div name. But now this very same table contains input fields (second form) with the same method. All ids and names are different, I can see the fields values with
    alert( $("input[name=id]").val() );';
Am I missing something ?

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


     <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="edit.php" method="POST">

     <select name="user" id="simple-post" onchange="this.value.submit()">
     <option value="">Select a person:</option>

 <option value="0">John</option>
     <option value="1">Peter</option>
 <option value="1">Heinrich</option>      

     </select>
     </form>

  <div id="simple-msg">
  </div>



<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{



$("#simple-post").click(function()
{

$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)

{

    $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");

    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();

    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

    $.ajax(

    {

        url : formURL,

        type: "POST",

        data : postData,

        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)

        {

            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');


        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

        {

            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');

        }

    });

    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action

    e.unbind();
});


$("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM

});


});

</script>

</body>
```

Now the edit.php page

```
<?php

$json_a=json_decode(json_encode($_POST),true);
$output=array();
$i=0;
foreach ($json_a as $key => $value){
   echo  $key . ':' . $value; // peut-être branché!
   $output[$i]= $value;
   $i++;
}

$array_user=array();
$array_user[0]=$output[0];
$array_user[1] ="Yes";
$array_user[2] ="mypass";

echo '<form name="ajaxform1" id="ajaxform1" action="SQL_user.php" method="POST">
';      

echo '<input type="text" name="id" size="3" value="' .$array_user[0]. '"/>';
echo '<input type="text" name="online" size="3" value="' .$array_user[1]. '"/>';
echo '<input type="text" name="password" size="20" value="' .$array_user[2]. '"/>';
echo '<input type="button"  id="simple-post1" value="Apply" />';    

echo '</form>';


echo '<br>';
echo'<div id ="simple-msg1">';
echo'</div>';




echo '<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{



$("#simple-post1").click(function()
{

$("#ajaxform1").submit(function(e)

{

    $("#simple-msg1").html("<img src='."'loading.gif'".'/>");

    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();

    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

    $.ajax(

    {

        url : formURL,

        type: "POST",

        data : postData,

        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)

        {

            $("#simple-msg1").html('."'<pre><code  class=".'"prettyprint"'.">'+data+'</code></pre>');


        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)".'"

        {

            $("#simple-msg1").html('."'<pre><code class=".'"prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='."'+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');

        }

    });

    e.preventDefault();
    e.unbind();

});


".'$("#ajaxform1").submit();
});


});

</script>';

?>
```

The second form doesn't work...

Comment: i only see one form, or are you dynamically adding the form after the first ajax call, is that what is in `data`?

Comment: the other form is almost the same (in another php page) called by the action of the first one

Answer (score 0):

you have put the following code to run if an element with `id=simple-post` gets clicked. notice, `.submit` is nested inside `.click`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#simple-post").click(function () {
       $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
        //code to execute on submit action goes here
       }

        $("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
    });
});
```

so the EventHandler on form submit will registered ONLY AFTER an element with `id=simple-post` gets clicked which is the reason, ajax request is not happening & form gets submitted normally.

Did you mean the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ajaxform").submit(function (e) {
        $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code
class="prettyprint">' + data + '</code></pre>');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX     Request Failed<br/> textStatus=' + textStatus + ', errorThrown=' + errorThrown + '</code></pre>');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind();
    });
    $("#simple-post").click(function () {
        $("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
    });

});
```

The above code will set EventHandler on form submit on `$(document).ready`. The form will get submitted via ajax/xhr either when:

1. Submit button form is pressed.
2. An element with `id=simple-post` gets clicked.(`Run Code` button)

Is this what you intend on doing?

Comment: the id simple-post is the button, but this id name and the others are different for the second form. But you're right I think the eventHandler stayed to the first one.. How can I switch to the second one. The thing's weird all works except the datas...

Comment: so what is your question? I am unable to understand what you are are asking. so if can explains, perhaps using examples & live code that might be cool.